# Posted event does not turn up with pygame.event.get()

Tags: python, sdl, pygame

I am putting together a component-entity game engine using Pygame, and I am using custom Pygame Userevents as my messaging system (the way the different subsystems within the engine can communicate without real knowledge of each other).

The messaging system works by attaching a list of event types to a system.  On each update cycle of the Engine class (which manages the systems), a filtered list of the events for that system is passed to the system, so that it can act on those events.

I have a component factory which creates component objects, attaches a reference to the object to an event, and then posts the event.  In the problematic code I am testing, I am posting an `ADDINPUTCOMPONENT` event (a custom Pygame Userevent) after creating an `InputComponent` object.

In my testing code you can see that I create an input system, install it on the engine with the proper event types, then create an input component, which should fire off the event.

I have verified that the code posting the event is occurring.  I have also verified that the engine is binding the events to the input system properly.

You can see in my update function for `InputSystem`, I should be handling the event that is posted from the factory, however I never see the event in the list of events returned by `pygame.event.get()`.

**Engine**

```
class PygameEngine(object):
    def __init__(self, systems=None):
        self.systems = list() if systems is None else systems

    def install_system(self, system, event_types=None):
        new_system = SystemEntity(system, event_types)
        self.systems.append(new_system)

    def update(self, time, events):
        for i in self.systems:
            i.system.update(time, 
                filter(lambda x: x.type in i.event_types, events))
```

**System**

```
class InputSystem(object):

    def __init__(self, components=None):
        # a map of lists, map keys are input devices, list items are
        #   components mapped to that device
        self.components = defaultdict(list) if components is None else components

    def update(self, time, events=None):

        for device, components in self.components.items():
            for comp in components:
                comp.last_state = copy.deepcopy(comp.state)
                print comp.state

        for event in events:

            # system events
            if event.type == ADDINPUTCOMPONENT:
                self.components[event.device].append(event.component)
                print "Added new input component"
            elif event.type == REMOVEINPUTCOMPONENT:
                self.components[event.device].remove(event.component)
            elif event.type == UPDATEBINDINGS:
                pass
```

**Factory**

```
def create_component(self, type, **props):
        component = None

        # InputComponent
        if type == 'input':
            device = props['device']
            entity_id = props['entity_id']
            # TODO: convert bindings to a bidict
            bindings = dict() if not 'bindings' in props else props['bindings']
            component = inputs.InputComponent(entity_id, bindings)
            new_event = event.Event(ADDINPUTCOMPONENT, device=device, component=component)
            event.post(new_event)
```

**Test Code**

```
inp = inputs.InputSystem()
eng.install_system(inp, (ADDINPUTCOMPONENT, REMOVEINPUTCOMPONENT,
                         UPDATEBINDINGS, pygame.KEYDOWN,
                         pygame.KEYUP, pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN,
                         pygame.JOYBUTTONUP, pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN,
                         pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP))
t_entity = factory.create_entity()
t_bindings = {
    'up': pygame.K_UP,
    'down': pygame.K_DOWN,
    'left': pygame.K_LEFT,
    'right': pygame.K_RIGHT
}
t_inp_component = factory.create_component('input', device=-1,
                                           entity_id=t_entity.entity_id,
                                           bindings=t_bindings)
```

**The Game Loop**

```
while not(done):
    last_time = current_time
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    time_since_last_update = current_time - last_time
    events = pygame.event.get()

    eng.update(time_since_last_update, events)
```

Comment: Your question is howto fire custom events, or why the event is getting filtered?

Comment: No, the question is why is the event not showing up in the list returned by `pygame.event.get()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I discovered where my problem is.  From the documentation on `pygame.event`:

> All events have a type identifier. This event type is in between the
>   values of NOEVENT and NUMEVENTS. All user defined events can have the
>   value of USEREVENT or higher. It is recommended make sure your event
>   id’s follow this system.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html

`NOEVENT` is a "constant" of value 0, `NUMEVENTS` is 32, and `USEREVENT` is 24.  Posting an event with a type value of 32 or greater causes pygame to essentially drop the event, it appears.  This means you only have 8 possible values for custom events (`NUMEVENTS` - `USEREVENT`).

The event I was not seeing be posted was 39.  It was defined like this:

```
ADDINPUTCOMPONENT = USEREVENT + 15
```

I tried changing it to `USEREVENT + 1` and it worked.

Essentially, if you want to have more than 8 types of custom events, you will just have to add a property to the events you post which allows you to distinguish between the event types.

Also, this limitation appears to be carried over from SDL:
http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdluserevent.html